# Is it possible to change iphone mode from silent to ringing?

Tags: iphone, ios6

some one tell if that possible now in iOS 6.0 ???

if yes give me just a hint to do it ,and if not i found an app on apple store do that but it not 100% perfect.

i hope i get an clear answer ???

[the application](http://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/autosilent/id474777148?mt=8)